# Is wicket:label needed with wicket:for?

Tags: wicket

In the past I have built labels for my form like this:

```
<label wicket:for="name"><wicket:label><wicket:message key="name"></wicket:message></wicket:label>:</label><input wicket:id="name" type="text"/>
```

Do I still need to use the `wicket:label` tag? I am not using `wicket:label` in wicket 7 and it seems to work fine. I may not be understanding the purpose of using wicket:label. It seems like `wicket:label` is just additional markup. Below is what I am doing now. Is this correct?:

```
<label wicket:for="name"><wicket:message key="name"></wicket:message>:</label><input wicket:id="name" type="text"/>
```

This example is related to [Wicket XHTML tags](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket's+XHTML+tags#Wicket%27sXHTMLtags-Attributewicket:for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the JavaDoc of `AutoLabelResolver` and `AutoLabelTextResolver`.

The `<label wicket:for="name">` is handled by `AutoLabelResolver`. It links the HTML `label` tag to the HTML form component (in your case the `input` tag) by filling in the correct ID in the HTML `for` attribute of the label. It also adds css classes to the label tag for for example errors, so you can style the text in the label tag in case of an error.

The `<wicket:label>` has two purposes. If you give it a value either by the `key` attribute (as you did) or by having some text between the tags, the text is set as the label model of the Java FormComponent, which then is used in validation messages like this `'${label}' is required.` (see `LabeledWebMarkupContainer#setLabel` and `LabeledWebMarkupContainer#getLabel`).

If you don't assign any text to the `<wicket:label>` tag, then it is used as output. That means the value of the label model of your Java FormComponent is used to replace the tag.

If you have no `<wicket:label>` in the HTML markup and no label model set in your Java code, then your Java FormComponent will have an empty label model and Wicket falls back to using the Wicket ID as label. So depending on how your Wicket IDs look, you will get validator messages like `'user_name' is required.` instead of something nice looking like `'User name' is required.`

Comment: Your response was helpful. I was looking at AutoLabelResolver, but not at the AutoLabelTextResolver JavaDoc. I always use a properties file for every label and do not set my label model in my Java code, so I wasn't running into the scenario where wicket:label could be useful. My conclusion is that there does need to be an element in the label tag when using wicket:for. In my case, wicket:message, or a wicket:label, will work. If I use the wicket:label, I do not need the for attribute or text in the element.